# Generate dynamic form and store the data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For a part of my next project I'm looking for the following information.
I'm trying to make an application for something like scouts, all the supervisors will have a user account on the application and the supervisors will be able to manage the members of the scouts. I'm looking for a way to let the supervisor decide what information they would like to store about the member. This will then be converted to a form so they can easily add new members.
What is the best way to make a dynamic form and store the data in a database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: generally speaking, people are much more likely to help you once you've tried to solve the problem yourself and are facing a problem with some existing code. Come back after you've written down some code and someone will probably help you then

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways to do that, so I don't know if this is the best with the little information you give us about your "case scenario".

I'll do create this tables:
**forms** (hold the form basic info and supervisors reference)
**forms_fields** (with an Elquent relatinship tipy "belongsTo")

Check Laravel documentation on Eloquent [here>](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)